# Resiudals of linear regression between two correlated explanatory variables as a new explenatory variable

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection, residuals, feature-engineering

I'm starting a new data science project with few explanatory variables, so I'm trying to keep as much variability as possible.

Also I have a lot of response variables, so don't really now what I want to do in the end (what response variable I want to predict for example). For the moment I'm just looking for insights and doing data visualisation.

Doing such, I've noticed two really correlated explanatory variables :

[image]

Their correlation coefficient is 0.8465772, so if I want to use a ML algorithm to predict one of the response variables, it would not be great to keep both.

Would it be a good idea to perform a linear regression between these two variables, and to replace one of the variables by the residuals of the regression ?

If so, does the "direction" of the regression (var1 ~ var2 or var2 ~ var1) is important ? Considering that the coefficient of determination is the same in both models?

Here are the results of the two regressions performed with R's lm() function :

[image: var1 explained by var2]

[image: var2 explained by var1]

And here are the plots of the residuals of both models, so what i would use as a new explanatory variable :

[image]

[image]

Maybe it's important to mention that individuals are ranked by time, so Index is like a temporal variable.

If you know anything about using residuals as an explanatory variable I'm listening.

Thank you :)

Comment: Those residuals are pretty interesting, but what’s wrong with including both variables in your model?

Comment: Please can you provide some contect, and explain what these variables are, how they were measured and what your research question is ?

Comment: Also, please show us the residuals when you include both variables in the model 0.85 correlation itself does not preclude retaining both.

Comment: This has the appearance of data mining devoid of important questions.  And beware of methods that work only with linear parametric models, such as using partial residuals.